# stack unwinding in exception c++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, stack-unwinding

I started to learn the subject of exceptions in C++.
I encountered the term "stack unwinding" which means, to my understanding,
that whenever exception is thrown, and there is no catch block inside the "throwing function", the function stack will "unwind", and by this all local object's d'tor will be called (and the same will also happen in the outer functions untill a suitable catch block will be encountered).

My question:

suppose the exception was thrown inside a try block with suitable following catch,
will the d'tor will be called for all objects defined inside the try block?
or to all objects defined in the try block until the exception occured?  or to no object at all, and they will "wait" for the function to exit?

Answer (score 2):

The semantics is that any local variable declared in a block should be destroyed when the control leaves the block (a function is a named block with parameters that are local variables). So when you leave a try-block any locally created variable will be destroyed and its appropriate dtor called. Everything that was created is destroyed, if something was not created, it simply cannot be destroyed. The only thing that is not destroyed is the exception objet itself if it is thrown (of course).

From the C++ spec:

> **15.2 Constructors and destructors 1.** As control passes from the point where an exception is thrown to a
>   handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects constructed
>   since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are destroyed
>   in the reverse order of the completion of their construction
>
> **15.2 Constructors and destructors 3.** The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed
>   on the path from a try block to the point where an exception is thrown
>   is called “stack unwinding.”